# including a .js file into in ejs template to manipulate the DOM does not work

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to add an event listener to my ejs templates.
in my app.js i have included this code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

and i have the following in my ejs temp

```
<script type="text/javascrpit" src="/js/show.js"></script>
```

also my show.js is something like this:

```
a=document.querySelector(".name")
a.style.color="pink"
```

my document structure is this:

```
 app.js
 /public
  /js
    /show.js
  /css
```

the included css works fine but js does not

This is my ejs template and this works fine:

```
<p class="name">Click this</p>
<script>
     a=document.querySelector(".name")
     a.style.color="pink"
</script>
```

Comment: When your ejs load. Is **Click this** already pink?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with your example is basically applying the color:pink to the paragraph immediately when the page loads. If you wanted to make an event listener on the paragraph so that when you click it it will turn pink you could do something like this.

```
<p class="name" onclick="changeColor()">Click this</p>
<script>
   function changeColor(){
          var a = document.querySelector(".name")
          a.style.color="pink"
   }

</script>
```

Hope this helps!